# how to split a word after special character

Tags: html, css

How do I make it so that the string stays constrained to the width of 150, and wraps to a new line on the hyphen?

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  12333-2333-233-23339392-332332323
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to do exactly that

Comment: Don't see the problem here..

Comment: Browsers are smart enough to break the line at a space ` ` or a hyphen "`-`", when a full string is wider than its container's width. As others have noted above, your code with `150px` container and its string with hyphens (`-`) seems to work exactly as you described. If you need to account for string variants that might _not_ contain a hyphen (`-`), see this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Text/Wrapping_Text) about wrapping and breaking.